# VBA to run specific queries

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table containing business priorities and the name of the query that is used to generate the results for each.

Is it possible to loop through this table and where it finds a query in the database with the same name, run it?

The closet thing I have found is below but I don't want to input my full query codes into a table.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_28284655.html

Answer (score 0):

This will execute every query name that is in your table.  It fills a recordset with the query names and then loops through and executes each one.

```
Dim sql As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim myQuery As String

sql = "Select myQuery from myTable"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

Do While Not rst.BOF And rst.EOF

    myQuery = rst(0)
    DoCmd.OpenQuery myQuery, acViewNormal
    rst.MoveNext

Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Let me know if you need to check to see if the query exists before you execute it. If so, I can add the code to search the querydefs collection for a query with the same name and only execute it if a match is found.

Comment: Thanks.  would I replace myTable  with the name of the actual table?

Comment: That's right. Just replace your table and column names in the SQL string.